# runtime error: Conversion from string "y" to type 'Boolean' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

I need help with the following code, as it is not working:

```
    Do While answer = "Y" Or "y"
        num = "0"
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number")
        num = Console.ReadLine
        total = total + num
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue Y/N")
        answer = Console.ReadLine
    Loop
```

Comment: Have you [thoroughly searched for an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/search) before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps _you_ get a more specific and relevant answer!  See also [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and [What makes a good question?](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Comment: @DanPichelman Yes I have thoroughly search for an answer and could not find anything hence why I posted this question.

Comment: What is not working? What error do you receive? We need a little more detail than "it's not working"

Comment: @DerekSchlesselman I receive a runtime error: Conversion from string "y" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.

Comment: Try `Do While answer = "Y" Or answer = "y"`

Comment: @Logan You could have also done it like this: `Do While answer.ToUpper = "Y"` executing only one compare.

Comment: @Logan - in the future, it is best to include descriptions of the errors you receive in the body of the question.  The "Conversion not valid" error is the key part of this issue and it should included.

Comment: ToUpper would be better in this case, however in a generic case (with two different letters, you could have used `{"A","B"}.Contains(answer)`.

Answer (score 5):

In VB.NET, logical and bitwise operators have lower precedence than comparison operators so asking

```
Do While answer = "Y" or "y"
```

is the same as asking

```
Do While (answer = "Y") or "y"
```

For the first condition, `answer = "Y"` can be true or false, for the second condition, `"y"` is neither true nor false - it's a string, so the statement does not make sense.

Your second test should include the variable test to. Like this :

```
Do While answer = "Y" Or answer = "y"
```

`answer = "y"` will be interpreted as `True` or `False` by the compiler wheter the expression is true or not.

It is like asking :  "Is `y` the value inside my `answer` variable ?"

Simply trying to convert `y` to a Boolean (True or False) like you're doing right now will result in a conversion error like the one you get.